# None if the following functions can be called with the Arguments supplied Jetpack Compose Error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I keep getting this error whenever I try to use a textfield in Compose, I have tried both Textfield implementations, ie one with a String value and TextFieldValue arguments but still get the error, I have also tried using
`var text = rememberSaveable{mutableStateOf("")}`
and
`var text by remember {mutableStateOf("")}`. I have also tried hoisting the State which is what I wanted to do in the first place but still get the error
[image]

Here's the code

```
fun SearchAppBar(
    query: String,
    onQueryChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onExecuteSearch: () -> Unit,
    scrollPosition: Int,
    selectedCategory: FoodCategory?,
    onSelectedCategoryChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onCategoryChangePosition: (Int) -> Unit,
) {

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        color = Color.White,
        elevation = 8.dp,
    ) {
        Column {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(.9f)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    value = query,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onQueryChanged(it)
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = "Search")
                    },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
                    ),
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Search)
                    },
                    onImeActionPerformed = { action, softKeyboardController ->
                        if (action == ImeAction.Done) {
                            onExecuteSearch()
                            softKeyboardController?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()
                        }
                    },
                    textStyle = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface),
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
                )


            }
            val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                    .horizontalScroll(scrollState)
            ) {
                scope.launch {
                    scrollState.scrollTo(
                        scrollPosition
                    )
                }

                for (category in getAllFoodCategories()) {
                    FoodCategoryChip(
                        category = category.value,
                        isSelected = selectedCategory == category,
                        onSelectedCategoryChanged = {
                            onSelectedCategoryChanged(it)
                            onCategoryChangePosition(
                                getAllFoodCategories().indexOf(selectedCategory)
                            )
                        },
                        onExecuteSearch = {
                            onExecuteSearch()
                        }

                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the combination of parameters contained in only one of the implementations. You can't, for example, use `keyboardOptions` alongside `onImeActionPerformed`.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited accordingly, I also found that you can't use the ```backgroundColor``` property it must have been deprecated

Comment: Yes, is has been. That's what I wondered initially. When you do not specify a version for Compose in the question, we consider the latest version at the time of writing to be applicable. So, always do mention the version of that's not the case. You can find it in the project kennel build file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `backgroundColor` property isnt valid anymore, use `colors:`. Also as pointed out by Richard Onslow Roper in his answer, look through the constructor of the TextField and see which properties are not part of your the Version of TextField you want to use

Don't do

```
          TextField(
                    value = query,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onQueryChanged(it)
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = "Search")
                    },
                  
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
                )
```

do this instead

```
          TextField(
                    value = query,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onQueryChanged(it)
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = "Search")
                    },
                  
                    colors=  TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
                    )
                )
```